# JavaScript Auto Page Reload

Tags: javascript

When I run a calculation in my application, your return value is printed on the screen when I use Firefox works normally. But when I use the Chrome and Safari browsers, the result appears on the screen and then disappears, giving the user no time to confirm the result.

The code for printing the value on the screen is this

```
document.getElementById("resultado").value = (eto.toFixed(2) + " mm/dia");
```

The rest of the code is :

```
function tanque() {
    // validação do valores de entrada
    if(document.getElementById("bor").value == "") {
        alert("Entre com o valor da bordadura!");
        return false;
    }

    if((document.getElementById("bor").value < 1) || (document.getElementById("bor").value > 1000)) {
        alert("Valor da bordadura deve ser entre 1m e 1000m.");
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("ur").value == "") {
        alert("Entre com o valor da umidade relativa!");
        return false;
    }

    if((document.getElementById("ur").value < 30) || (document.getElementById("vento").value > 84)) {
        alert("Valor da umidade relativa deve ser entre 30% e 84%.");
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("vento").value == "") {
        alert("Entre com o valor da velocidade do ventor!");
        return false;
    }

    if((document.getElementById("vento").value < 1) || (document.getElementById("vento").value > 8)) {
        alert("Valor da velocidade do vento deve ser entre 1m/s e 8m/s.");
        return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("eca").value == "") {
        alert("Entre com o valor do ECA!");
        return false;
    }

    var bor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bor").value);
    var ur = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ur").value);
    var vento = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vento").value);
    var eca = parseFloat(document.getElementById("eca").value);

    var kp;
    kp = (0.108 - (0.0286 * vento) + (0.0422 * Math.log(bor) + (0.1434 * Math.log(ur)) - (0.000631 * (Math.pow(Math.log(bor)), 2) * Math.log(ur))));

    var eto;
    eto = (kp * eca);

    document.getElementById("resultado").value = eto.toFixed(2) + " mm/dia";
}
```

Comment: is it a form input? Can you also share the html code?

Comment: If you have a submission button that is triggering `tanque`, make sure it has `type='button'` and not `type='submit'`